# What's the phrase that ends with "up" and which somewhat means "someone who considers everything taboo and don't discuss anything"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary, phrases

So, it's a phrase like 'stuck up' or 'pent up', etc. It's been bothering me for a while now but I just can't remember the phrase. I think it starts with 's' and ends with 'up' and it means something along the lines of "someone for whom everything is sacred and they are very traditional and conservative in their thinking and can't challenge conventional wisdom". I know it's not a precise definition and I'm probably confusing two words/phrases here but as I said, it's bugging me no end and I'd really appreciate any help in finding this mystery phrase.

Comment: synonyms for [tight-lipped](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tight-lipped) - ***buttoned-up, clammed up, closemouthed, mum, not talkative, reserved, restrained, reticent, secretive, taciturn,...*** But there could be many reasons why someone doesn't like to discuss anything, or say what they think. ***Close[d]-minded***, for example, doesn't necessarily imply someone thinks all subjects are "taboo" - just that they're unlikely to discuss anything because there's no chance they'll ever change their mind about anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think close-minded is pretty close to what I have in mind but as I said, I am pretty sure it ended in the preposition "up" and starts with the letter 's'. For some reason, I keep getting back to "stuck up" but it is not the right word

Comment: Well, my *guess* is that any compound adjective of the general form sXXX-**up** with the meaning you seek is probably at the very least "slangy" (and very likely something of a "nonce-coinage" that would only be understood *in context*). But we'll see. Maybe in the right context ***clammed-up*** would do. Or even ***shuttered-up***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my apologies, I think I was looking for the phrase "hung up on everything". I don't know why I believed it started with an 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably mean '*uptight*'.

Someone who is uptight is *rigidly conventional, as in manners, opinions, and tastes.*

Comment: I think I was looking for the phrase "hung up on everything". I got it by searching for the synonyms of "upright".